# Why is my spotlight not showing up in Unity3d?

Tags: unity-game-engine, light

[Image of the thing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btEZb.png) Basically what it says on the tin. Trying to use a spotlight to illuminate objects in my game, only it doesn't show up. I've already tried doing all the setting changes described in other questions about the spotlight on here (the intensity is 2 in the screenshot, but I changed it to many different numbers), but no change. There aren't any errors being thrown that I can see since I changed the indirect multiplier to 0. [Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWic6.png) If there's an easy answer to this, please tell me.

Comment: Do you mean the icon for the light in the editor or the actual light in the game?

Comment: The light in-game. I haven't actually been looking at the icon, so that might be gone as well, but I've no clue.

Comment: If you remove the main directional light and set the intensity very high (>1000) is the problem still there